# How to calculate the turnover 1 month ago with the day and month values ​kept as int in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my table:

| id | Total | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 410 |
| 2 | 4 | 121 |
| 3 | 7 | 630 |
| 4 | 8 | 629 |
| 5 | 9 | 101 |

Date part is saved as int month and day. How to find the total amount made in the previous month of the current month?

Comment: January 21st. This is how we store our data

Comment: 21st January of what, @sitera? 1576, 1866, 2022, 3106? Dates are made up of a day, month *and* year.

Comment: Can you not just do `SELECT SUM(Total) FROM YourTable WHERE Date >= MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1 AND Date < MONTH(GETDATE())` this obviously doesn't take into account year rollovers, but that is a problem with your data, as mentioned by others.

Comment: Only month and day are kept. Year field not kept.A pril 10,
January 21,
june 30,
june 29

Comment: Then it isn't a date, @sitera ... Also what is `111`? 11 January of some arbitrary year, or 1 November of some arbitrary year? How do you tell? Is 1231 before or after 11? How do you know if it's the day before or 364/365 days later?

Comment: Sorry I can't help fix the way the data is saved.In addition, the table only keeps records of that year.

Comment: Does your data really have once the dot and once the comma as the decimal separator? I'll start by formulating the solution as if not.

Comment: I think the total area is more understandable.

Comment: Do you at least zero-pad the day portion - such that Jan 1 is recorded as 101?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
Select Date_/100 as Date_Month, Sum(Total) as MonthlyTotal From YourTable
Where MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1 = (Date_/100)
Group By (Date_/100)
```

See a demo from *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f2f47c94b70d710f1c06e4a4a495c76)*.

Comment: Note, for days less than 10, the date should be three digits, i.e. 1st of Jan = 101. Otherwise, the query should be modified wih a `case expression` to handle dates with two digits.

Comment: You are welcome, but I advice you to rethink about the way you are storing the date, Good Luck :)

Comment: sorry i can't fix it. I didn't decide this :(

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the comments made above. I get it that you can't change the way that you store your "dates" . But you should make whoever made that decision miserable. They are asking for trouble like that.

Having said that -

I rely, here, on the fact that the division of two integers, in SQL Server, if it is not an integer already, is truncated to the next lower integer, and returned as integer.

```
WITH
-- your input, don't use in final query ...
-- I renamed the third column more aptly to "monthday"
indata(id,Total,monthday) AS (
          SELECT 1,3.00,410
UNION ALL SELECT 2,4.55,121
UNION ALL SELECT 3,7.40,630
UNION ALL SELECT 4,8.00,629
)
-- real query starts here - replace following comma with "WITH"
,
per_month AS (
  SELECT
    monthday / 100 AS monthno                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  , SUM(total) AS monthtot
  FROM indata
  GROUP BY monthno
-- ctl  monthno | monthtot 
-- ctl ---------+----------
-- ctl        1 |     4.55
-- ctl        4 |     3.00
-- ctl        6 |    15.40
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM per_month
WHERE monthno=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - 1;
-- out  monthno | monthtot                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-- out ---------+----------
-- out        6 |    15.40
```

Comment: The query result looks like this.  monthno 6 6 monthtot 8.00 7.40.  Pretty close. But right now it's not enough. Thanks for help

Comment: What is exactly your expected result?

Comment: Expected result should have been 15.40 but this query
6 7.40
6 8.00
shows as a result

Comment: You must have selected from the un-grouped original input, and never grouped. My final result is : `monthno | 6`  and `month tot | 15.40`. But no worries ...